# Does the set of differences of an uncountable real subset has an interior point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ be uncountable. Does its set of differences $\triangle X := \{a-b \mid a, b \in X\}$ has an interior point? I.e. is there some $c \in \triangle X$ and some $\delta >0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $(c-\delta, c + \delta )\subseteq \triangle X$?

The motivation for this comes from the fact that this is true for the cantor set, I wondered if this has something to do with the specific construction or if it's actually just about it being uncountable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is false. No two points of a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) differ by a rational number, and thus no such $c$ can be found, as $(c -\delta, c+\delta)$ would always contain at least one rational number.

Comment: You actually proved that it's false.

Comment: And uncountability wouldn’t be enough anyway: in models of set theory in which the continuum hypothesis is false you could take an uncountable set $X$ such that $|X|<|\Bbb R|$, and the set of differences would have the same cardinality as $X$, but the cardinality of any open interval is $|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I do wonder if there are less exotic counterexamples.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That is a wonderful proof. I never thought that the independence of the continuum theorem would ever help me haha.

Comment: I think exotic is in the eye of the beholder.  Vitali sets feel less exotic because they have a recognized name, but I think they require the axiom of choice on the reals.  If the cardinality of the continuum is large, @Brian M. Scott's example only needs the axiom of choice over $\aleph_1$.  Yours is a good answer to the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan I meant less exotic than either mine or Brian's. Perhaps one that doesn't need choice at all.